# FormBuilder Field Name same as user input fetches null user input

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I am using Bot Builder Version 3.9.1.

In my formbuilder i am referring to a class below.

```
[Serializable]
public class AccountsQuery
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets an account name.
    /// </summary>
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the refined account name.
    /// </summary>
    public string RefinedAccountName { get; set; }
}
```

Code to invoke form dialog

```
IFormDialog<AccountsQuery> accountEntryFormDialog = FormDialog.FromForm(this.BuildAccountEntryFormFirst, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
context.Call(accountEntryFormDialog, this.ResumeAfterAccountEntryFormDialog);
```

Form dialog code

```
private IForm<AccountsQuery> BuildAccountEntryFormFirst()
        {
            IResourceManager resourceManager = this.GetService<IResourceManager>();
            string accountNameEntryPrompt = string.Format(resourceManager.GetStringResource(ResourceConstants.AccountNameEntryTextFirstTime), this.accountsOwned.Count);

            return new FormBuilder<AccountsQuery>()
                .Field(nameof(AccountsQuery.AccountName), accountNameEntryPrompt)
                .Field(
                        nameof(AccountsQuery.RefinedAccountName),
                        resourceManager.GetStringResource(ResourceConstants.RefinedAccountNameEntryText),
                        active: (state) =>
                        this.GetAccountCount(state.AccountName) > this.minAccountCount)
                .Build();
        }
```

During the flow, when user is asked to enter RefinedAccountName, and user enters "Account" or "Name" then i get user entered value as null and not "Account" or "Name" in state.AccountName when GetAccountCount method is called. Is this an expected behavior from Bot Framework?

Comment: Please provide more details. What version of the Bot Builder SDK are u using. How are u instantiating the form? Do you have a repro to take a look at?

Comment: @EzequielJadib i dont have code in shareable repo as of now. But i have provided more details. Please let me know if that works.